# Twilio programmable video notifications

Tags: notifications, twilio, twilio-video

I developed a solution to allow my users to get in touch through video calls.
However, for iOS I can't manage to trigger notifications (CallKeep for example) to warn a user that someone is trying to contact him.

Would you have solutions to propose to me because I can't find anything conclusive.

Comment: The [Twilio Video quickstart repo](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios) has an example of an application that uses CallKit, have you taken a look at that? Is the issue that you can't send notifications from your server? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have found a solution exactly on the link that you provide so this is great thanks. 
Sorry for the delay of my answer.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer since it helped. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Twilio Video quick start application](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios) has a [CallKit example](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/tree/master/VideoCallKitQuickStart). Please take a look at that and see what you can learn.